# Syntax Error : Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, project

```
 FAIL  src/test/search.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\learn-react\node_modules\axios\index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import axios from './lib/axios.js';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    > 2 | import axios from 'axios';
        | ^
      3 |
      4 | const Search = () => {
      5 |   const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('Programming');

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Search/Search.js:2:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total                                                                                      
Tests:       0 total                                                                                                
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.556 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Watch Usage
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

I want to solve this issue...

Comment: I just removed some irrelevant tags; for tips on using tags effectively, check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) under **Include all relevant tags**, and for more info, see [What are tags, and how should I use them?](/help/tagging)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.